# Code not wrapping in listings even though breaklines=true

Tags: listings, code, wrap

I read that enabling breaklines in listings will make the included code wrap, but it does not in my case. Maybe something is interfering with this function?

Full code is shown below:

```
\ifdefined\docdefined
\else
    \documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt, openright]{report}
    \input{include_start}
    \begin{document}
\fi

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

% START DOCUMENT

\begin{appendices}
\makeatletter

\chapter{GUI Code}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    XML
\section{Code XML}

\lstset{language=XML, 
numbers=left, 
frame=single, 
commentstyle=\color{dkgreen}, 
basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily}, 
keywordstyle=\color{blue}, 
%identifierstyle=\color{blue}, 
stringstyle=\color{mauve},
captionpos=t,
showstringspaces=false,
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=true,
tabsize=3,
caption={\protect\filename@parse{\lstname}\protect\filename@base\text{.}\protect\filename@ext},
}

\begin{frame}

\lstinputlisting{C:/Users/hab/SW/GUI/android/AndroidManifest.xml}    

\end{frame}

\end{appendices}

% END DOCUMENT
\ifdefined\docdefined
\else
    \input{include_end}
    \end{document}
\fi
```

Comment: Unless we see what `AndroidManifest.xml` contains, it will be difficult to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Is it really unclear what I am asking here? The title is very specific and full code example is provided with explanation at top. I would appreciate feedback how this is unclear to avoid further unclear questions.

Comment: Even though you provide what looks like a MWE, because you don't provide your XML file, 1) your code is not compilable, and 2) we have no way of figuring out what, in that XML file, might prevent line breaking. You managed to answer your own question because *you* can see what that file contains, but nobody else here can. That's why your question was closed as unclear. In the future, always make your MWE self-contained and compilable (have a look at the `filecontents` package for writing to external files); you will likely get at leat one satisfactory answer more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple.

I had:

```
breakatwhitespace=true
```

which mean it will only break at whitespace. Since some of the XML does not have whitspaces and long strings, it will not wrap!

Solution:

```
breakatwhitespace=false
```

It does now wrap even if no whitespace is found.